# SQL Query returns Null Values

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a User entity with role types Marketer, Managing Director and General Manager . **When the UserRole Managing Director logs In**, I want the userrole Managing Director to only see customers assigned **to Usertype Marketers with the same Branch ID as the Managing Director**.

I have a custom Query in the **customer repository** that returns a null result.

```
@Query("SELECT customer from Customer customer join customer.marketer marketer "
 + "where marketer.branch = :director") 
List<Customer> findByUserBranch(User director);
```

This is the User entity

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler"})
public class User {

    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String firstName ;
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="user_name", unique=true)
    private String userName;
    
    private String password;
    private String Gender; 
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Branch.class, 
     fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn(name="branch_id") 
    private Branch branch;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date createdDate;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
    name = "users_roles", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<>();
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserStatus status;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="marketer",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=Customer.class)
    private List <Customer> customer;
```

This is the controller class

```
@GetMapping(value="branch/customers") 
public List<Customer> getListByBranch()
{ Authentication authentication =
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); 
User loggedInUser = userRepo.findByUserName(authentication.getName()); return customerRepo.findByBranch(loggedInUser); 
}
```

UPDATED :

This is the **Customer** class

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler"})
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8348682056500740593L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String firstName ;
    private String lastName;
    private String gender;
    private String Address; 
    private String maritalStatus;
    private String category;
    private String motherMaidenName;
    private String idType;
    private String  idNumber;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    
    @Column(nullable = true, length = 64)
    private String photos;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date registrationDate;
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, 
     fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn(name="marketer_id") 
    private User marketer ;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer_id",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=Investment.class)
    private List<Investment> investment;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't make a comment, so i would ask to also give us the customer.class .

Comment: I just updated the question with the customer class

Comment: Did you try the query in the database ? if yes, please share it with me.

Comment: No i did not try in the database.

Comment: try this => List<Customer> findByUserBranch(@Param("director") User director);
I added @Param("director") ,so that know in the query, see if it works.

Comment: just tried it and still getting same empty result

Comment: Is class Branch similar to class User ? because what i see here u make condition for it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved . I changed the User object to branch object.

```
@Query("SELECT customer from Customer customer join "
            + "customer.marketer marketer "
          + "where marketer.branch = :branch") 
      List<Customer> findByUserBranch(Branch branch);
```

Then refactored the controller class

```
@GetMapping(value="branch/customers") 
      public List<Customer> getListByBranch(Principal principal)
      { 
      User loggedInUser = userRepo.findByUserName(principal.getName());
      Branch branchId = loggedInUser.getBranch();
      return customerRepo.findByBranch(branchId); 
      }
```